# how to display tabs in more than one row having the extra tabs coming one row up rather than one row below?

Tags: css

When there are more tabs in a row when it cant be displayed in a single row , I want he new tabs to be displayed in the row above than row below. For example,
[here comments is coming one row down the line , I want comments to appear on the row above other tabs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87E92.png)

Please help me how to do it in css.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want Comments to appear right above Demographics?

Comment: yes please, or Demographics as the first one and all the other tabs coming in the row below. Either wise is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at 
`flex-wrap:wrap-reverse`
 in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gothic/Nf8PR/

Comment: thanks so much... works fine. Maybe I feel like having more, I am looking to display demographics as the first one and all other tabs coming on the row below. Could you see an option to do that. Many thanks..